State Space modeling UCM Local Linear Trend with not fixed transition matrix
I want modeling on library statsmodels.tsa.statespace (0.14.4) for Python 3.10.11 an UCM Local Linear Trend with the addition of two exogenous, plus an arbitrary number of exogenous trying to capture seasonality and a slight modifications on level equation as follow.
Observation equation

Level equation

Trend equation

with  as time difference between observations or time increments because the observations are not equidistant in time.
Follow we have a general form for state space.
 with 
 with 
Setting aside the exogenous variables below are the matrices of the corresponding State Space model.
Design matrix 

States equation 

Transition matrix 

Covariance observation matrix 

Covariance states matrix 

How do I insert the exogenous variables into the matric definition of the state space?
I create exogenous data frame as follow
f_year = DeterministicProcess(X.index, period=period, fourier=harmonics).in_sample()
X_exog = pd.concat([X, f_year], axis=1)

and after i call my definition of state space model as follow
kwargs = {'delta_t': delta_time[start : end]}
mod = models.DiscreteTimeLocalLinearTrend(Y[start : end], X[start : end], **kwargs)
    
mod_fit = mod.fit(maxiter=500, method='powell', disp=0)
    
kwargs = {'delta_t': delta_time[end : end + steps_predictions]}
y_pred = mod_fit.forecast(steps=steps_predictions, exog=X[end : end + steps_predictions], **kwargs)

below the definition of my DiscreteTimeLocalLinearTrend
class DiscreteTimeLocalLinearTrend(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    def __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs):
        # Model order
        n_exog = exog.shape[1]
        k_states = 2 + n_exog 
        k_posdef = k_states

        exog = exog.values
        delta_t = kwargs.get('delta_t').values
        
        # Initialize the statespace
        super(DiscreteTimeLocalLinearTrend, self).__init__(
            endog=endog, exog=exog,
            k_states=k_states, k_posdef=k_posdef,
            initialization='approximate_diffuse',
            loglikelihood_burn=k_states,
            **kwargs
        )

        # Design matrix
        self.ssm['design'] = np.zeros((1, k_states, len(endog)))
        self.ssm['design'][0, 0, :] = 1  # trend
        self.ssm['design'][0, 1, :] = 0  # level
        self.ssm['design'][0, 2:, :] = self.exog.T  # exogenous

        # Transition matrix
        self.ssm['transition'] = np.zeros((k_states, k_states, len(endog)))
        for t in range(len(endog)):
            self.ssm['transition'][:2, :2, t] = np.array([[1, delta_t[t]], [0, 1]])
            self.ssm['transition'][0, 2:, t] = exog[t]

        # Selection matrix
        self.ssm['selection'] = np.eye(k_states)

        # State covariance matrix
        self.ssm['state_cov'] = np.eye(k_posdef)

    @property
    def param_names(self):
        return ['sigma2.measurement', 'sigma2.level', 'sigma2.trend']

    @property
    def start_params(self):
        return [np.std(self.endog)]*3

    def transform_params(self, unconstrained):
        return unconstrained**2

    def untransform_params(self, constrained):
        return constrained**0.5
    
    def clone(self, endog, exog=None, **kwargs):
        return self._clone_from_init_kwds(endog, exog=exog, **kwargs)

    def update(self, params, *args, **kwargs):
        delta_t = kwargs.get('delta_t').values
        params = super(DiscreteTimeLocalLinearTrend, self).update(params, *args, **kwargs)

        # Observation covariance matrix
        self.ssm['obs_cov',0,0] = params[0]

        # State covariance matrix
        self.ssm['state_cov'] = np.zeros((self.ssm.k_states, self.ssm.k_states))
        np.fill_diagonal(self.ssm['state_cov'], np.real(params[1:self.ssm.k_states+1]))

        # Design matrix
        self.ssm['design'][0, 2:, :] = self.exog.T

        # Transition matrix
        for t in range(len(self.endog)):
            self.ssm['transition'][:2, :2, t] = np.array([[1, delta_t[t]], [0, 1]])

I modify the function _get_extension_time_varying_matrices of class MLEModel from
# Create extended model
if extend_kwargs is None:
    extend_kwargs = {}

to
# Create extended model
if extend_kwargs is None:
    extend_kwargs = kwargs

for passing delta_t on clone method (i think it's a library bug).
After resolving this problem i get an error in the update method because delta_t is not found in the kwargs. If i comment code transition matrix on update method the code runs but I notice from the forecast graph that the influence of exogenous variables is not taken into account.
Leaving the code of the transition matrix update commented out and using the transition matrix initialisation as a normal local linear trend from
for t in range(len(endog)):
    self.ssm['transition'][:2, :2, t] = np.array([[1, delta_t[t]], 
                                                  [0, 1]])
    self.ssm['transition'][0, 2:, t] = exog[t]

to
self.ssm['transition'] = np.eye(k_states)
self.ssm['transition'][:2, :2] = np.array([[1, 1], 
                                           [0, 1]]) 

then the influence of the exogenous variables is considered.
Where am I going wrong?
